# Can we change the extension of video and play it?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, download

Currently I am downloading a ".mp4" video and saving it in a folder. I want to hide it from gallery. I know how to hide a folder. Currently I am saving it in a different extension for ex. like ".sss" and it is saving properly. Now how can I play that video in my application.

I tried to change the extension and in file and try to play it, but it is not working, here is my code

```
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"downloadFolder"+"/"+"video1.sss".replace(".sss",".mp4");

    JCVideoPlayer mJcVideoPlayerStandard = (JCVideoPlayerStandard) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
    mJcVideoPlayerStandard.setUp(extStore.getPath(),JCVideoPlayerStandard.SCREEN_LAYOUT_NORMAL, "Normal");
mJcVideoPlayerStandard.showContextMenu();
```

I am using this path to play the video,and I am usign JcVideo player lib for playing the video, here is the gradle for it

```
compile 'fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.4'
```

When I am saving the file in ".mp4" format I am able to play the video. But when I use different format,I am not able to play it. Any help will be preferable

Comment: Generally app developers use App private folder to store images and videos which they don't want to display on gallery.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is to rename the file to mp4 before you play it?

If so the code above is replacing the the '.sss' with '.mp4' in the search string rather than renaming it in the file system.

In other words the line:

```js
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"downloadFolder"+"/"+"video1.sss".replace(".sss",".mp4");
```

simply translates to:

```js
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"downloadFolder"+"/"+"video1.mp4";
```

As your actual file is still video1.sss you get an error when you try to play a file named  video1.mp4 as it can't be found.

If you do want to rename a file you can do it like this:

```js
File file1 = new File("Path of file");
File file2 = new File("Path with new name for the file");
boolean ok = file1.renameTo(file2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply can't do it! by changing the extension of a video file you can't play it. because no matter what its extension is, the Audio and Video format coding format won't change by changing extension name. If a player can't play such extension, it is not in its supported video codec.

The Audio and Video format define how a video file is build byte to byte. check this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format).

Comment: then i should say, are you sure you are not changing video1.sss to video1.mp4.sss?

Comment: is there any error or what? what happen in android monitor.

Comment: File not exist,

Comment: try to save the file in new different directory and see what happens.

Comment: same as before, file not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136925/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-ranjan-das).